# Как создать новый экземпляр класса с новыми рандомными данными?

Tags: python, классы, pydantic

Условно есть такой код:

```
import random


class Test:
    number: str = random.randint(100, 500)


test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()

assert test1.number == test2.number
```

Создаются 2 разных объекта, но значение **number** у них будет всегда одинаковое.

Как создать несколько экземпляров класса, в которых будут каждый раз генерироваться случайные значения `number` (и чтобы вручную не передавать туда `number=...`)? Чтобы выполнялось такое условие:

```
test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()

assert test1.number != test2.number
```

Comment: Пояснение. Важен именно такой подход в создании класса, без функции инициализации экземпляров. Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Еще одно пояснение. Необходимо, чтобы оставалась возможность передать свое значение **number** при создании нового экземпляра. А если не передано - тогда генерировать рандомное.

Answer (score 7):

В обычном случае, вам подойдёт вариант, предложенный @strawdog:

```
class Test:
    number: str
    
    def __init__():
        self.number = random.randint(100, 500)
```

Если же вы используете `pydantic.BaseModel`, то данные можно передать в `super().__init__(**data)` при инициализации:

```
class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    number: str

    def __init__(self, number=None, **data):
        super().__init__(
            number=random.randint(100, 500) if number is None else number,
            **data
        )
```

Comment: Во втором примере я не смогу самостоятельно указать **number** при создании экземпляра, а нужно также учитывать и эту возможность.

Comment: @Gentleman, изменил ответ: в \_\_init\_\_ можно передать number, а если он не указан, значение None по умолчанию заменится случайным числом при super инициализации.

Answer (score 5):

А вы не пробовали записывать класс в каноническом виде, с функцией инициализации экземпляров? в противном случае рандомизация у вас происходит один раз для родительского объекта.

```
import random

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = random.randint(100, 500)


test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()
test1.number==test2.number  #False
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую **pydantic** для создания модели, поэтому данный способ не подходит для меня.

Comment: @Gentleman это крайне важное уточнение обязано присутствовать в тексте вопроса

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Я осознал, что не указал в вопросе все требования. Дописал их комментариях.

Answer (score 5):

Определение поля в классе в **pydantic** - это значение по умолчанию для всех экземпляров, для которых такое значение не задано. По-этому, то, что вы наблюдаете - это нормальное ожидаемое поведение.

Если вам нужно создать экземпляры со случайными значениями, то делайте это в конструкторе:

```
class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    number: str

    def __init__(self, **data):
        if 'number' not in data:
           data['number'] = random.randint(100, 500)
        super().__init__(**data)
```

Ну и еще есть [factoryboy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) как раз для генерации тестовых данных.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Начал изучать информацию о factoryboy и наткнулся на [pydactory](https://pypi.org/project/pydactory/). Решение отпишу.

Answer (score 4):

В `pydantic` и `dataclasses` можно указать `default_factory` ("фабрику" значения по умолчанию) для поля. Обычно это используется для инициализации поля пустым списком (или другим контейнером) например `default_factory=list`, но можно передать лямбду, которая вызывает `random.randint(100, 500)`.

Вариант с использованием `pydantic`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import random


class Test(BaseModel):
    number: str = Field(default_factory = lambda: random.randint(100, 500))


test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()

print(repr(test1))
print(repr(test2))
```

Пример вывода:

```
Test(number=387)
Test(number=487)
```

Аналогично, на `dataclasses`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import random


@dataclass
class Test:
    number: str = field(default_factory = lambda: random.randint(100, 500))


test1 = Test()
test2 = Test()

print(test1)
print(test2)
```

Пример вывода:

```
Test(number=254)
Test(number=247)
```

Answer (score 4):

Всем спасибо за ответы, они действительно правильные. Но мне кажется более изящным и читабельным следующее решение:

```
import random
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydactory import Factory


class Test(BaseModel):
    number: int


class TestFactory(Factory[Test]):
    number: int = lambda: random.randint(100, 500)


test1: Test = TestFactory.build()
test2: Test = TestFactory.build()

assert test1.number != test2.number  # True
```

Напишите, пожалуйста, в комментариях, что вы думаете по поводу данного решения.

Comment: Мне нравится этот вариант, потому что тут заполнение случайными данными не зашито в объект намертво, а реализуется отдельным классом, в итоге в "боевом" режиме объект работает с теми данными, которые в него передадут, а например для тестов можно написать фабрику, которая будет заполнять объект какими-то фейковыми данными.